# Extracting Data using following Query

Tags: sql

I am trying to extract required data from tables but I need to add another table

on top of full join tables but it does not bring required data as I needed for

analysis.

```
SELECT pupil.pupil_id,english.pupil_id AS english_pupil_id,english.dis_id,english.element,english.points,maths.pupil_id
maths_pupil_id,maths.dis_id,maths.element,maths.points
FROM pupil,
(
SELECT P.Pupil_ID,P.dis_id, GR.element,GR.points
FROM [pupil] P,[Grade_Result] GR
WHERE P.Pupil_ID = GR.Pupil_ID
AND   GR.element IN('English','english','eglish')
AND   gr.points IN(9,8,7,6) 
)english
FULL JOIN   
(
SELECT P.Pupil_ID,P.dis_id, GR.element,GR.points
FROM [pupil] P,[Grade_Result] GR
WHERE P.Pupil_ID = GR.Pupil_ID
AND   GR.element IN('Maths', 'maths')
AND   gr.points IN(9,8,7,6)
)maths
ON  maths.Pupil_ID = english.Pupil_Id
```

Comment: That is non standard SQL, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: what changes should I use to make it standard.

Comment: The `[` and `]` are invalid for an identifier in standard SQL